# AS3: Have 4 checkboxes, need to be able to select not more than 3

Tags: actionscript-3, checkbox

I have 4 checkboxes. If i select 3 and after select 4, then the oldest checkbox should be unchecked. I make an `Array` with 3 elemets and populate with checkboxes. But i can't uncheck the oldest checkbox. Am I doing something wrong?

```
firstButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction);
SecButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction);
TherdButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction);
FourButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction);

var num:Number = 1
var txt:Array = new Array (1+num)
for (var i=1; i<3;i++){
  txt[i]=null
}
i=1
function myFunction(But:MouseEvent):void {
   if(But.currentTarget.selected == true) {
     txt[i]=But.currentTarget.name
 i++
 if (i==3){i=1}
   } else {
     for (var d=1;d<3;d++) {
       if (txt[d]==But.currentTarget.name){
         txt[d]=null
         i=d
       }
     }
```

Comment: _txt_ is an array that stores the name of the clicked target. When you uncheck a box, its name is removed from the array, but there is nothing in the code the affects the checked state of a box..

Comment: you mean need make set 2 array with property checkbox. Caz Null is none and if have name then checkbox is checked. So problem is how provide in last array and set property object uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i make it self :) This is good try make all universal without names. Only change variables and MaxCheckBoxes self set max.

```
var checkMax:Number=3
var i:Number = 1;
var maxChecks:Number = 4;
var ArrayMaxBut:Array=new Array(checkMax+1);
var ArrayBut:Array=new Array(maxChecks+1);
for (i=1; i<=maxChecks; i++)
{
    ArrayMaxBut[i] = getChildByName("button"+i);
    ArrayMaxBut[i].selected=false
    ArrayMaxBut[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunction);
}

for (i=1; i<=maxChecks; i++)
{
    ArrayBut[i] = null;
}
i = 0
function myFunction(Click:MouseEvent):void
{   
    if (Click.currentTarget.selected == true)
    {i++
        if(i>checkMax){i--
            ArrayBut[i].selected=false
            ArrayBut[i]=null
            }
            ArrayBut[i] = Click.currentTarget;

    }else{i--}}
```